# can we get list of video formats / codecs supported by Google Cloud video intelligence API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

Can you please help with list of video formats and codecs that are supported by Google Cloud Video Intelligence API

Answer (score 0):

The API supports common video formats, including .MOV, .MPEG4, .MP4, and .AVI. Per https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/

Comment: I need complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Video Intelligence uses [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to process the videos, so the formats supported by FFMPEG are also supported by it.